# update a single field in indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

The following working code is used to setup my question:

```js
myRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase('myDatabase')
myRequest.onsuccess = function() {
 var myRequest
 
 myRequest = indexedDB.open('myDatabase')
 myRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(response) {
  var myDatabase
   ,myObjectStore
  
  myDatabase = response.target.result
  myObjectStore = myDatabase.createObjectStore('myData',{autoIncrement:true})
 }
 myRequest.onerror = function(response) {
  debugger
 }
 myRequest.onsuccess = function(response) {
  var myTransaction
   ,myObjectStore
   ,myRequest
   ,obj = {}
  window.myDatabase = response.target.result
  myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'],'readwrite')
  myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
  obj.field1 = 'a'
  obj.field2 = 'b'
  myObjectStore.add(obj)
 }
}
```

Q: How do I say the equivalent of:

```
update myData set field2='c' where key=1
```

Do I have to supply both field1 and field2 in a .put statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you must put the full object, e.g.

```
myObjectStore.get(1).onsuccess = function(e) {
  var obj = e.target.result;
  obj.field2 = 'c';
  myObjectStore.put(obj, 1);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Your answer really helped me. One thing I noticed is that the primary key is not needed in the put statement because it's supplied in the get result.

Comment: If you put() without a key and the store has autoIncrement set, you will get a new record, not overwrite the previous record.... unless you're using in-line keys (i.e. the object store has keyPath specified, which your example does not.)

Answer (score -1):

```js
myRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase('myDatabase')
myRequest.onsuccess = function() {
 var myRequest
 
 myRequest = indexedDB.open('myDatabase')
 myRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(response) {
  var myDatabase
   ,myObjectStore
  
  myDatabase = response.target.result
  myObjectStore = myDatabase.createObjectStore('myData',{autoIncrement:true})
 }
 myRequest.onerror = function(response) {
  debugger
 }
 myRequest.onsuccess = function(response) {
  var myTransaction
   ,myObjectStore
   ,myRequest
   ,obj = {}
  window.myDatabase = response.target.result
  myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'],'readwrite')
  myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
  obj.field1 = 'a'
  obj.field2 = 'b'
  myObjectStore.add(obj)
 }
}
```

```js
myRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase('myDatabase')
myRequest.onsuccess = function() {
 var myRequest
 
 myRequest = indexedDB.open('myDatabase')
 myRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(response) {
  var myDatabase
   ,myObjectStore
  
  myDatabase = response.target.result
  myObjectStore = myDatabase.createObjectStore('myData',{autoIncrement:true})
 }
 myRequest.onerror = function(response) {
  debugger
 }
 myRequest.onsuccess = function(response) {
  var myTransaction
   ,myObjectStore
   ,myRequest
   ,obj = {}
  window.myDatabase = response.target.result
  myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'],'readwrite')
  myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
  obj.field1 = 'a'
  obj.field2 = 'b'
  myObjectStore.add(obj)
 }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation!